# JEE Custom Unpackaged tags file attributes being set pre-set with form values

Tags: jsp

I noticed the my custom JEE unpackaged tag attributes were inheriting values from the jsp EL environment. Is there a way I can turn this off? This is happening on Tomcat 7.0 using Struts 2.31.

Here is my use case

My jsp is using "id" as a form field and my button tag is also using the "id" attribute. It happens when I don't set the "id" value in the button tag. The "id" will inherit values from the jsp EL environment.  I don't want this behavior.

### jsp:

```
<t:button type="button" onclick="...">
    <s:text name="button.label.save"/>
</t:buton>
:
:
<input name="id" id="resourcesIdCheckbox${i}" type="checkbox" value="${id}" />
```

### WEB-INF/tags/button.tag

```
<%@tag description="Button tag" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ attribute name="id" %>
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" <c:if test="${!empty id}">id="${id}"
</c:if> ... >
:
</button>
<jsp:doBody/>
</button>
```

---

Now the workaround is to set the id field for the button but there are cases when I don't want to explicit the id field. For example i have a 8 tabs with 8 forms. I don't want to set the id for every single button, less code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. You will get subtle bugs in your code if you don't explicitly use pageScope for non-required jsp attributes.
e.g.

```
<%@ attribute name="id" %>
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" <c:if test="${!empty pageScope.id}">id="${pageScope.id}"
```

if jsp tag attribute is required then you don't need to qualify the scope.
e.g.

```
<%@ attribute name="id" required="true" %>
```

I have seen plenty of examples custom tags on the web without the mention of scope. I hope this helps someone.

Steve